# Dependency error: Unable to install Anjuta IDE

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 15.04, dependencies, anjuta

I'm unable to install anjuta studio in Ubuntu 15.04 using the Gnome 3.16 DE.

This is the output of terminal:

```
shivam@shivam-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-2.4.9-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjavascriptcoregtk-2.4.9-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libjavascriptcoregtk-2.4.9-0'
shivam@shivam-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install anjuta
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 anjuta : Depends: libdevhelp-3-2 (>= 3.12.0-2~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the output of apt-cache:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy anjuta libdevhelp-3-2 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25
anjuta:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:3.14.0-1
  Version table:
     2:3.14.0-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
libdevhelp-3-2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.14.0-1
  Version table:
     3.14.0-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.8-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.4.8-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Another output of install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdevhelp-3-2 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 (= 2.4.8-1ubuntu2) but 2.4.9-0ubuntu1~15.04~webkitteam1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Another output of apt-cache:

```
shivam@shivam-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:
  Installed: 2.4.9-0ubuntu1~15.04~webkitteam1
  Candidate: 2.4.9-0ubuntu1~15.04~webkitteam1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.9-0ubuntu1~15.04~webkitteam1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.8-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy anjuta libdevhelp-3-2 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25`

Comment: Give me the output of the command above

Comment: @A.B.  Edited the question details with the output of above command.

Comment: Force the installation via `sudo apt-get install ibdevhelp-3-2 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25` and add the output into your question.

Comment: And where is the output of the command above? =)

Comment: Hi @A.B. added the output of above command to description.

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0`

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the following packages

- `libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (2.4.8-1ubuntu)`
- `libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 (2.4.8-1ubuntu2)`
- `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (2.6.2+dfsg1-4ubuntu1)`

but not `libjavascriptcoregtk-2.4.9-0`.

---

And you **had** the PPA `ppa:webkit-team` in your system before and therefore `libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 (2.4.9-0ubuntu1~15.04~webkitteam1)` installed. **If you need the PPA (again) jump at the end of my answer and ignore the next steps.**

---

The problem is, `libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25` from the Standard Ubuntu Repositories needs exactly `libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 (2.4.8-1ubuntu2)`.

The fast solution is, downgrade the package `libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0` via

```
sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0=2.4.8-1ubuntu2
```

**but you should use the commands below** to downgrade all packages, upgraded by the PPA `ppa:webkit-team`

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webkit-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webkit-team
```

**In the future, use `ppa-purge` to remove a PPA from your system.**

---

If you need the PPA, add it again and use it and your problem will be solved, too

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webkit-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Still doesn't work after installing version 1.0-0 while 3.0-0 and 4.0-18 were already installed.

Comment: Also edited the question details with the output of command as requested.

Comment: Do not attempt to downgrade. It removed much important components of the system.

Comment: What is "much important"? Add the PPA again and purge it as described or add the PPA and use it.

Comment: I'm unable to login after downgrading. It uninstalled Gnome DE and now falls back to lightdm. But I'm unable to select the DE and can't login even after entering my password.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You've just written that software is removed and I was wondering what software. After that I wrote to you that you should add the PPA and then everything will work, too.

Comment: After adding any ppa the software doesn't get automatically installed. The essential components of both Unity and Gnome were removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29560/discussion-between-a-b-and-shivam-arora).

Comment: Can I chat with the StackExchange app?

Comment: If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** at the left-hand side of my answer, now turning it into beautiful green. That means, the answer is valid. And because I've shown you how to install your desktop again, you can still give me a Upvote.

Comment: Done. But everyone else be careful when downgrading the package.

Comment: Everything can be reinstalled. Sometimes that's the only way.